# How to copy columns from one csv file to another csv file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, text-files, file-handling

I have input.csv file with below format

```
number day
5      Mon
4      Tue
3      Wed
2      Thu
```

and I want to copy this data to another output.csv file with reverse order

```
number day
2      Thu
3      Wed
4      Tue
5      Mon
```

I have written this code but don't know how to proceed with reverse thing

```
cols = ["number", "day"]
file_path = "input.csv"
pd.read_csv(file_path, usecols=cols).to_csv("output.csv", index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- t.csv

```
number,day
5,Mon
4,Tue
3,Wed
2,Thu
```

- script

```
with open('t.csv','r') as file:
    f=csv.reader(file)
    data=[]
    for row in f:
        data.append(row)
    header=data[0]
    rows=data[1:]
    rows.sort(reverse=False)

with open('t_out.csv','w',newline='') as file_out:
    f=csv.writer(file_out)
    f.writerow(header)
    f.writerows(rows)
```

- t_out.csv

```
number,day
2,Thu
3,Wed
4,Tue
5,Mon
```

Comment: I am dealing with csv files, will this work for them also? @DevScheffer

Comment: First of all, this code is also reversing the first column headers - "numbers" and "day" and secondly it prints out all the data in a single row and not as my desired output. @DevScheffe

Comment: This is working perfectly now, Thanks @Devscheffer