# Copy one column from CSV file and paste into another CSV file

Tags: python, csv

I have 2 csv files, and 2 columns in each. I'm trying to take column 2 from input.csv and paste it into column 3 in output.csv.

It have it setup like this.

input.csv

```
apple, #123
toast, #324
```

output.csv

```
apple, yes
toast, no
```

Now I want to take column 2 from input.csv and paste it into column 3 in output.csv and output like so:

```
apple, yes, #123
toast, no, #324
```

Thanks

Comment: You can use a package called Pandas, and merge 2 CSV, the output would be as you wanted it.

Comment: You can specify the column you want to join on, but you would need to add headers to both files so the Pandas can do their magic.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

Comment: The output does not match the input.  Shouldn’t it be `toast, no` in the output?  Additionally, is this a key-matching exercise, or simply chop and paste?

Comment: Does this answer your question ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67247004/how-to-copy-columns-from-one-csv-file-to-another-csv-file)]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

###### reading two csv files

```
data1 = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
data2 = pd.read_csv('output.csv')
```

###### using merge function , {‘left’, ‘right’, ‘outer’, ‘inner’, ‘cross’}, default is ‘inner’ , anyone can be used as per need

```
output1 = pd.merge(data1, data2,  how='inner')
```

###### displaying result

```
print(output1)
```